# Constructor for card class wont compile

Tags: java

im making a card game for my assignment but am having issues with making my card class compile, i get the following message, package myDeck does not exist and im really not sure what im doing wrong, here is my code. please can anyone help?

DeckofCards class

```
import java.util.Random;


public class DeckOfCards
{

public int suit;
public int card;
public Random r;
public final int MAXSUIT = 3;
public final int MAXCARD = 12;


/**
 * Constructor for objects of class DeckOfCards
 */
public DeckOfCards()
{
    // initialise instance variables
    r = new Random();
    shuffleDeck();
}

public void shuffleDeck()
{
    suit = r.nextInt(MAXSUIT);
    card = r.nextInt(MAXCARD);
}

public int getCard()
{
    return card;
}

public int getSuit()
{
    return suit;
}
```

}

Card Class

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Card
{

private DeckOfCards myDeck;
public int card;
public int suit; 
public String cardName;
public String suitName;


public Card()
{
   card = new myDeck.getCard();
   suit = new myDeck.getSuit();      

}

public String showCard()
{
    return (cardName+ " of "+suit);
}

public void changeCard()
{
   new Card();
}

public String getCardName()
{
    return cardName;
}

public String getSuitName()
{
    return suitName;
}

public void setCardName()
{
    switch(card)
    {
        case 0  :
        cardName = "2";
                    break;
        case 1  :
        cardName = "3";
                    break;
        case 2  :
        cardName = "4";
                    break;
        case 3  :
        cardName = "5"; 
                    break;
        case 4  :
        cardName = "6";
                    break;
        case 5  :
        cardName = "7";
                    break;
        case 6  :
        cardName = "8";
                    break;
        case 7  :
        cardName = "9";
                    break;
        case 8  :
        cardName = "10";
                    break;
        case 9:
        cardName = "Jack";
                    break;
        case 10 :
        cardName = "Queen";
                    break;
        case 11 :  
        cardName = "King";
                    break;
        case 12 : 
        cardName = "Ace";
                    break;
        default :
    }
}

public void setSuitName()
{
       switch(suit)
       {
           case 0 :
           suitName = "Diamonds";
                        break;
           case 1 :
           suitName = "Hearts";
                        break;
           case 2 :
           suitName = "Spades";
                        break;
           case 3 :
           suitName = "Clubs";
                        break;
           default :
           suitName =  "No suit";
                        break;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: While the current answer solves the problem, I think that a `DeckOfCard`s is a group of `Card`s, so `DeckOfCard` should have a dependency on `Card` class, not otherwise. I would worry more about the design rather than this runtime issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `myDeck` before it's initialized. It has to rather be:

```
public Card() {
   myDeck = new DeckOfCards();
   card = myDeck.getCard();
   suit = myDeck.getSuit();
}
```

As a side note, there's no need to maintain two additional members (`card` and `suit`), since you can get this data from the `myDeck` variable.

You should also reconsider your design, because a the `DeckOfCard` should be dependent on the `Card` class, not otherwise. Currently, whenever you create a `Card` object, another `DeckOfCards` is created, too. Which is semantically wrong.

If I were you, I would put both classes in one package and decorate the `Card` constructor with the `protected` modifier, so that it can be instantiated only within this package. Also, I would remove the `myDeck` member from the `Card` class and introduce a `Set<Card>` member in the `DeckOfCards` class.

Comment: Or `new myDeck().getCard();` so OP can know he was missing `()`.

Comment: Yes, but then two `DeckOfCards` will be created, which I'm not sure if it's right. :)

Comment: The advice you gave results in cheating. Recreating the deck for each Card constructor is very, very likely to produce duplicate cards because the Deck is reshuffled each time...

Comment: I agree with you. It is more like a design problem

Comment: @MarounMaroun I don't think that there is a `myDeck` class. The `new` keyword is completely wrong there.

Comment: Well, design can be improved, but even as it is, the syntax problem should be repaired without creating another problem.

Comment: But not even a static deck is going to help. No idea how the Cards are going to be used.

Comment: I have to create a game where you hold three cards and you have three turns to try and swap low scoring cards for high scoring cards. i see what your saying about design the problem i have is i was given 4 classes in DeckOfCards, Card, HandOfCards, and CardGame in the assignment and not sure if im allowed to change that, is their any other way i could prevent duplication?

Answer (score 0):

Adding something to the hints that the design can stand improvement. If someone thinks this shouldn't be here: comment, and I'll promptly remove it. - What one usually does is to create a Deck as a Collectíon of 52 Card objects:

```
class Card {
   Suit suit;
   Rank rank;
   Card( Suit suit, Rank rank ){...}
}
class Deck {
   List<Card> cards = ...
   Deck(){
       for( Suit suit: EnumSet.allOf(Suit.class) ){
           for( Rank rank: EnumSet.allOf(Rank.class) ){
               cards.add( new Card( suit, rank ) );
           }
       }
   }
}
```

You can shuffle the deck before you deal a hand.